# Couldn't find or load main class org.sonar.runner.Main

Tags: sonar-runner

I have installed sonar but when I want to analyze a project using sonar runner, I get the following error:

```
Error: Couldn't find or load main class org.sonar.runner.Main
```

The directory in which I have installed doesn't contain any spaces, So the possibility of getting this error due to wrong naming is ruled out.
Plz help me.

Comment: Need more details, like how are you invoking the runner ? are you using nexus to store the runner, are you using gradle ? or ant to execute the task, what does you configuration looks like, what versions are you using what version of Java are you using, are you on Linux, or windows ? etc etc